# How to make IBM MQ listener process slowly using spring java application

Tags: java, spring, jms, rx-java, ibm-mq

We are trying to migrate our legacy system to Micro service
With Paas environment, we have scheduler jobs to trigger and put messages in MQ one by one and we have MQ listener in our Microservice to get message and create request and send request to external party.

Here the problem comes our micro service is capable doing Asynchronous call to external service, but our external service is not able to handle Asynchronous call so it is returning wrong data.
For example, we are hitting external service with 40 to 60 request per minute and external service is capable to handle only 6 request per minute.

So how can I make the MQ listener to process slowly.

I have tried reducing `setMaxConcurrenceConsumer` to 1 and 
Used `observable.toblocking.single()` to make the process to run in only one thread.

We use RxJava in our micro service.

Comment: Based on the description shouldn't the requests queue up at the external queue manager?  Why does this cause it to return the wrong data?

Comment: Mq is giving correct data only but external service is not able to handle Asynchronous process so it is giving wrong data

Comment: You may want to look at the possibility of making synchronous calls to your external service from microservice. This way you the calls to the external service are sequenced. Better to ask the owner of the external service to investigate and fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Shashi, we have tried to make synchronous call but it's failed because the event is triggered by MQ only, then we also tried allowing only one thread at a time but still it is so fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In long term approach we are planning to migrate the External service to as well.

In short time i have fixed it using the observable.toblocking.single() ,thread.sleep(), and setMaxConcurrenceConsumer() to 1 so only one thread will run at a time. which will avoid the Asynchronous call to external service.The sleep time will set dynamically with some analysis done on the external service.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either your micro service or the external service is not following the use case for Request-Reply messaging.

(1) Is the external service setting the Reply's message Correlation ID with the Request message's Message ID?

(2) Is your micro service performing an MQGET with the matching option of getting by Correlation ID.

You can blame the external service for the error but if your micro service is actually picking up the wrong message then it is your application's fault.  i.e. Does your micro service simply get the "next" message on the queue?

Read this answer: [How to match MQ Server reply messages to the correct request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021283/how-to-match-mq-server-reply-messages-to-the-correct-request)

Here's a explanation (looks like from the 90's but has good information): https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReplyJmsExample.html